# How to see errors in PHPRunner?

Tags: phprunner

I am working on a website created in PHPRunner. I have created a page using custom view and added it in the side navigation bar using Menu Editor. But when I save & build the project. I am not able to see the page I created on the website. The software doesn't show any errors when I build the project. All I can see no changes for the new page on the website. I am not sure whats wrong with the software or how to trace for errors?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the group permission to see that page from the Administrator rights section.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for helping out! Your answer could use some more explanation or examples. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

If the web application you have created is using security, then you need to go to the admin area and allow permission for the admin to view the page.